# What package do I need for Cygwin's UBsan?

Tags: g++, cygwin, ubsan

I have a test script that grinds through various configurations. The script tests for the availability of [Undefined Behavior sanitizer (UBsan)](https://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/), and then performs the build if available. Here's the test:

```
$CXX -x c++ -dM -E -fsanitize=undefined -std=c++11 - < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    HAVE_UBSAN=1
else
    HAVE_UBSAN=0
fi
```

The test above sets `HAVE_UBSAN=1` on Cygwin, which means GCC's Cygwin claims to support UBsan (otherwise, it would have produced an error). However, I'm catching a link error under both Cygwin i686 and x86_64:

```
...
g++ -DDEBUG -g2 -O2 -Wall -std=c++03 -fsanitize=undefined -march=native -pipe -c fipsalgt.cpp
g++ -DDEBUG -g2 -O2 -Wall -std=c++03 -fsanitize=undefined -march=native -pipe -c dlltest.cpp
g++ -o cryptest.exe -DDEBUG -g2 -O2 -Wall -std=c++03 -fsanitize=undefined -march=native test.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o ... ./libcryptopp.a
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lubsan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile:333: recipe for target 'cryptest.exe' failed
make: *** [cryptest.exe] Error 1
```

Obviously, whatever is needed was not installed with `gcc-core` or `gcc-g++`. I ran the setup program again and searched for ***`ubsan`*** but I got 0 hits.

What package(s) do I need for Cygwin's UBsan?

While I'm at it, I might as well ask about the next failure I expect to experience. What package do I need for Cygwin's Asan?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted to the mailing list http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-10/msg00493.html

Comment: Thanks Steven. I'm pretty sure this is a Cygwin issue. I'm closing our bug report ([Cryptest.exe fails to build under Cygwin-i686 with sanitizer flags](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/49)).

Comment: Does this mean that cygwin doesn't support ubsan?